# Keras/Theano custom loss calculation - working with tensors

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, theano

I'm struggling to write some tensor manipulation code for a custom loss function I'm using in Keras.

Basically, I'm trying to modify a binary_crossentropy loss by adding a weight that is calculated from a particular feature.

First thing I do is pass in my extra feature data to the custom loss by appending it to the y_true like this:

```
y_trainModded = numpy.append(y_train, MyExtraData, axis=1)
```

Which is then passed to the fit function like:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_trainModded, epochs=2500, .....)
```

Then extracted to make it usable like this:

```
def myCustomLoss(data, y_pred):
    y_true = data[:,:2]
    MyExtraData = data[:,2]
    ...
    ...
```

So far, that all works fine.  However, I'm struggling with a section where I want to only select the MyExtraData where I predicted '1'.  Intuitively, this would simply be something like:

```
ExtraDataWherePredicted1 = MyExtraData[y_pred > 0]
```

However, we're dealing with tensors, not numpy arrays. I tried casting to numpy arrays using eval(), but that didn't work. I also tried various approaches using keras.backend operations such as:

```
WherePredicted1 = K.greater( y_pred,0)
ExtraDataWherePredicted1 = tf.boolean_mask(MyExtraData, WherePredicted1)
```

Which I could then use to weight my loss such as:

```
return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_pred,y_true), axis=-1)-(K.mean(ExtraDataWherePredicted1))
```

But anything I try throws out various errors...I just can't figure out how to calculate *ExtraDataWherePredicted1*. I'm also finding it super hard to debug the loss function because I can't print() anything inside it, so it's very hard to double check to see if the arrays/tensors are what I expect them to be.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think I might have solved this - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have finally just solved this myself.

1) I changed my Keras backend to use TensorFlow instead of Theano, so that I could use:

```
tf.boolean_mask
```

This command was not available under the Theano backend and thus giving me errors.

2) I had to change my code slightly to work with the correct dimensions. It now reads:

```
WherePredicted1 = K.greater( y_pred[:,1],0.5) 
ExtraDataWherePredicted1 = tf.boolean_mask(MyExtraData, WherePredicted1)
```

Still finding it hard to debug/test a custom loss function, but it's looking like feasible values to might well be correct.